# How can I find the time between users session activity using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using SQL how can you find the time duration or time elapsed between each users session? For instance user_id 1234 had one session on 2017-01-01 00:00:00 and another session on 2017-01-02 (see table below). How can I find the time between the last session_end to beginning of their next session_start.

```
user_id|session_start       |session_end
1234   | 2017-01-01 00:00:00| 2017-01-01 00:30:30
1236   | 2017-01-01 01:00:00| 2017-01-01 01:05:30
1234   | 2017-01-02 12:00:09| 2017-01-02 12:00:30
1234   | 2017-01-01 02:00:00| 2017-01-01 03:30:30
1236   | 2017-01-01 00:00:00| 2017-01-01 00:30:30
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please update your tags so that you just have one database type, is it postgresql, redshift or sql server? please remove the tags that do not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
select user_id, session_start, session_end,
       session_start - lag(session_end) over (partition by user_id order by session_start) as time_diff
from the_table
order by user_id, session_start;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/NTVH38963

---

Subtracting one timestamp from another returns an [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) to convert that to minutes you can [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) the number of get the number of seconds the interval represents and divide them by 60 to get minutes:

```
select user_id, session_start, session_end,
       extract(epoch from 
                 session_start - lag(session_end) over (partition by user_id order by session_start)
               ) / 60 as minutes
from the_table
order by user_id, session_start;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the time in minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT dT.user_ID
      ,dT.max_session_start
      ,DATEDIFF(minute, (SELECT MAX(session_end)
                           FROM tablename T
                          WHERE T.user_ID = dT.user_ID
                            AND T.session_end < dT.max_session_start)
                      , dT.max_session_start
               ) AS minutes
  FROM (
         SELECT user_ID
               ,MAX(session_start) AS max_session_start
           FROM tablename
        GROUP BY user_ID
       ) AS dT
```